# Como fazer com que links abram em um iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

Como faço para que o menu da página `index.html` abra as páginas dentro do `iframe` contido no mesmo documento (`index.html`).

Por exemplo, ao clicar no *link* abaixo a página `contato.html` seja carregada dentro do `iframe` que está na página `index.html`.

```
<a href="contato.html">Contato</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se o o `iframe` do `index.html` foi declarado assim:

```
<iframe name="principal" src="pagina.html"></iframe>
```

O *link* será:

```
<a href="contato.html" target="principal">Contato</a>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/LinkIframe.html).

O alvo `principal` é o nome do `iframe`.

Comment: obrigado, funcionou legal!

Comment: Eu queria responder essa :D +1