# Link que muda o src do iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Como mudar o src do iframe de acordo com o clique de um botão?

Por exemplo, eu tenho esse conjunto de links:

```html
<li class="hover">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
        <span class="menu-text"> Jucesp </span>
        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
    </a>

 <b class="arrow"></b>

    <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="hover">
        <a href="https://www.jucesp.sp.gov.br/VRE/Consulta/ConsultaProcessos.aspx">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Processo Integrado de Viabilidade e Registro
        </a>
    
            <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
    
        <li class="hover">
            <a href="https://www.sil.sp.gov.br/consultar_solicitacao.aspx">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                Processo de Licenciamento
            </a>
    
            <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
    
        <li class="hover">
            <a href="https://www.jucesponline.sp.gov.br/Pesquisa.aspx">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                Ficha Cadastral Completa
            </a>
    
            <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

E mais abaixo um frame:

```
<iframe width="300" height="300">
    <p>Navegador não suporta <i>frames</i>.</p>
</iframe>
```

Como fazer para que quando o usuário clique em um dos links, ele mude programaticamente o `src` do `iframe`?

De preferência da maneira mais fácil, já que vou ter que repetir umas 20 vezes o código.

EXEMPLO

A pessoa clicou no Processo Integrado de Viabilidade..., em vez de mandar para outra URL, eu quero que o src do iframe mude para NESSE CASO `https://www.jucesp.sp.gov.br/VRE/Consulta/ConsultaProcessos.aspx`

Comment: Qual são os `src` que deveram ir pro iframe?

Comment: Possível duplicada de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82723/como-fazer-com-que-links-abram-em-um-iframe?rq=1

Comment: Os que tiverem no link que o usuário clicar